# Iterating through li elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a structure in my `HTML` code which looks a little like this.

```
<nav id="nav">
    <ul>
        <li>Li 1</li>
        <li>Li 2</li>
        <li>Li 3</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

To iterate through the list I am using `JavaScript` and the `jQuery` plugin. The code looks a little like this.

```
for(i = 1; i <= navSide.children("ul").children("li").length; i++) {
    console.log(navSide.children("ul").children("li:nth-child(i)").offset().top);
}
```

However, the problem with doing it this way is that I get an `Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: :nth-child`. What is the correct, most efficient, way to do what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `each()` loop

```js
$('#nav li').each(function() {
  console.log($(this).offset().top);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav id="nav">
  <ul>
    <li>Li 1</li>
    <li>Li 2</li>
    <li>Li 3</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

You cant use `nth-child` like that. Jquery have `each` method which will allow you to easy iterate through all `li` elements.

```js
$('li').each(function()  {
   console.log($(this).offset().top);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav id="nav">
    <ul>
        <li>Li 1</li>
        <li>Li 2</li>
        <li>Li 3</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```